# Unable to display uploaded image (saved in file system and stored location on database eg., C:\Database\.. ) in jsp using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a spring web MVC application. I have uploaded the images using Multipart and saved to file system(C:\Database\1.jpg). I am saving the file location to the database. Now, I need to display the images but donno what the reason is!! I am unable to display images.

Web.xml

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmaven"/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="C:/**" location="/" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="vendorDAO" class="com.springmaven.dao.VendorDAOImpl"/>
<bean id="sendEmail" class="com.springmaven.model.Email"/>
<bean id="hairStyleDAO" class="com.springmaven.dao.HairStyleDAOImpl"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seturstyle?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
<!--For FileUpload-->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="uploadTempDir" ref="uploadDirResource" />
</bean>
<bean id="uploadDirResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>C:/Database/</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<!--For Sending Mail-->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="setuastyle@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="msitmsit"/>

    <!-- The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions -->
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

HairStyleController

```
package com.springmaven.controllers;
import com.springmaven.dao.HairStyleDAOImpl;
import com.springmaven.model.HairStyle;
import com.springmaven.model.Vendor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HairStyleController {
@Autowired
HairStyleDAOImpl hairStyleDAO;

@RequestMapping(value = "/AddHairstyle")
public ModelAndView addHairstyleView() {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("vendor_AddHairStyle");
    return modelView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/EditHairstyleDetails")
public ModelAndView editHairstyleView() {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("vendor_editHairstyle");
    return modelView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ViewHairstyles")
public ModelAndView viewAllHairstyleView(HttpSession session) {
    Vendor v = (Vendor) session.getAttribute("vendor");
    List<HairStyle> hairstyles=hairStyleDAO.getAllVendorhairstyles(v.getEmail());
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("vendor_viewAllHairstyles");
    modelView.addObject("hairstyles",hairstyles);
    return modelView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addHairstyleForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addhairStyleForm(@ModelAttribute("hairstyle") HairStyle hairStyle, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files,
                             HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/AddHairstyle");


    File pics[]=new File[files.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = files[i];
        try {
            byte barr[] = file.getBytes();
            String orgfileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            int lastIndex = orgfileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            String extension = orgfileName.substring(lastIndex, orgfileName.length());

            String saloonName = hairStyle.getSaloonName();
            saloonName = saloonName.replace(" ", "");

            String path = request.getContextPath();
            File d = new File("C:\Database\");
            if(!d.exists())
                d.mkdir();

            File di = new File(d+ "\" + saloonName);
            if (!di.exists()) {
                boolean br = di.mkdir();
            }

            String hairStyleName = hairStyle.getHairstyleName();
            hairStyleName = hairStyleName.replace(" ", "");

            File dir = new File(di + "\" + hairStyleName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                boolean br = dir.mkdir();
            }
            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir+ "\" + hairStyleName + "_" + (i+1) + extension);

            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));

            bout.write(barr);
            bout.flush();
            bout.close();
            pics[i] = serverFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    hairStyle.setHairstylePics(pics);
    int i = hairStyleDAO.addHairStyle(hairStyle);
    if (i == 1) {
        modelView.setViewName("success");
    }
    else
    {
        modelView.addObject("error","Error occured during registration please do try again");
    }
    return modelView;
}
}
```

Now in view all hairstyles JSP, I am unable to load images. showing empty blank white space.

Can anyone please solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are storing images in FileSystem, You need to read the file path and get the image.

Here is the backend code(note that I used Spring framework)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showImage/{saloonName}/{folder}/{hairstyleName}/{imageName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getImage(@PathVariable(value = "saloonName") String saloonName,
                     @PathVariable(value = "folder") String folder,
                     @PathVariable(value = "hairstyleName") String haistyleName,
                     @PathVariable(value = "imageName") String imageName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Database" + File.separator + saloonName +
                File.separator + folder + File.separator + haistyleName + File.separator + imageName + ".jpg");
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't open image from " + "C:\\Database\\" + saloonName + "\\" + folder + "\\" + haistyleName + "\\" + imageName + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Whereas, In the front end

```
<img class="group list-group-image" src="/showImage/${hairstyles.get(i).hairstylePics[0]}"/>
```

Here In the above code, I have used Servlet for request/response model. 
             /showImage/{folder_path}/image_name 
when I request an image as specified above It will request mapping function to load the image from the filesystem and send the response as image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif format.